# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:(NSString*) inconsistency?

Tags: objective-c

While working on filtering my NSMutableDictionary based on user input, I created the following code:

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF beginsWith[cd] %@", searchString];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
NSArray *filteredKeys = [[myMutableDictionary allKeys] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

"searchString" is passed into the method with this definition:

```
(NSString*) searchString
```

This however resulted in the following exception:

> ...raised [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key...

The fix turned out to be:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginsWith[cd] %@", searchString];
NSArray *filteredKeys = [[myMutableDictionary allKeys] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

What I don't understand, is why the latter worked, and the former threw the exception. I have read a little bit on [key value coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html), but I don't understand how it applies here. (i.e. only by changing how the NSPredicate is defined) Can someone enlighten me?

**Update:**
In response to jtbandes comment, I went ahead and created a TestApp project to demo this problem. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/401317/TestApp1.tar.gz

Comment: You'll really have to show us the entire exception if you expect us to figure out what it means.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is [in the predicate programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-SW1).

> String constants must be quoted within the expression—single and double quotes are both acceptable, ... **If you use variable substitution using %@ ..., the quotation marks are added for you automatically**. If you use string constants within your format string, **you must quote them yourself**

[my emphasis]

`predicateWithFormat` puts the quotes in for you, but `stringWithFormat` doesn't.  Your first example would probably work if you did this:

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELF beginsWith[cd] '%@'", searchString];
//                                                                           ^  ^ single or double quotes
```

Comment: Indeed, the quotes fix the problem. Throwing a "valueForUndefinedKey" exception just seems like leading the developer down the wrong path I guess. (Invalid Predicate Syntax would be better I think) Maybe it's just my inexperience with objective-c.

Comment: @yanigisawa: it's not invalid syntax though.  If there are no quotes, it assumes it is a KVC key, so you are comparing the value of one key against another.  Under those circumstances, the exception makes sense.

Comment: Alright, I'll chalk it up to my being inexperienced with these compiler and runtime errors. Thanks for your help.