# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat not evaluating format specifier

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

I have a (to me) curious case with NSPredicate's `predicateWithFormat:` method.

Using the following I log the description of two NSPredicate instances to the console:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];

NSString *predicateFormatByHand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"self MATCHES 'chp%@_img[0-9]+\\.png'", myNumber];
NSPredicate *firstPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormatByHand];

NSLog(@"firstPredicate description: %@", firstPredicate);

NSPredicate *secondPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self MATCHES 'chp%@_img[0-9]+\\.png'", myNumber];

NSLog(@"secondPredicate description: %@", secondPredicate);
```

This outputs:

```
 firstPredicate description: SELF MATCHES "chp1_img[0-9]+.png"
secondPredicate description: SELF MATCHES "chp%@_img[0-9]+.png"
```

I would expect these descriptions to be the same.

Can someone explain why they are not?

(Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726467/nspredicate-predicatewithformatnsstring-inconsistency) I've played with various escape sequences for the embedded single-quotes but when doing so keep having NSPredicate complain that it cannot then parse the format string. I'd be grateful to know what's going on.)

UPDATE: one answer suggested it's an issue with using NSNumber rather than an int, so:

```
NSPredicate *thirdPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self MATCHES 'chp%d_img[0-9]+\\.png'", [myNumber intValue]];

NSLog(@"thirdPredicate description: %@", thirdPredicate);
```

I began with this originally, but alas the output is the same:

```
thirdPredicate description: SELF MATCHES "chp%d_img[0-9]+.png"
```

(Something means the format specifier is not evaluated.)

Comment: Try assembling the RHS in a stringWithFormat expression outside and then dropping it into the predicateWithFormat. I have found predicate with format to be uncooperative sometimes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simple: the parser used by `NSPredicate` assumes that anything inside the quote marks is a string literal, and does not attempt to do any substitutions on its contents. It you need to have a dynamic string value, you will have to build the string before substituting it into the predicate format string, as in your first example.

Answer (score 2):

...because the `predicate` is not such thing than `string`.

for any of the `predicate`s you should use two format specifier 100% safety only:

- one for the *key* (`%K`); and
- one for the *value* (`%@`);

you cannot format neither the *key* nor the *value* when you add them to the `predicate`. this is why your second (and third) `predicates` are not formatted inside the value.

you can format the *value* **before** you add it to the `predicate` like:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chp%@_img[0-9]+\\.png", myNumber];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", string];
NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
```

the result is:

```
SELF MATCHES "chp1_img[0-9]+\\.png"
```

...and never forget my first sentence: the `predicates` and the `strings` are not the same thing.

Comment: @DaveDeLong, yes, it is true. could you share the rest of format specifier what we can use in predicates? it seems you forgot to mention them in your comment...

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW2): "The format string supports `printf`-style format arguments such as `%x` (see “[Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943)”). Two important arguments are `%@` and `%K`."

Comment: @DaveDeLong, your comment is much better with these details.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of

> %@ is a var arg substitution for an object value

in the "Predicate Programming Guide" is that `%@` can only be used for substituting a value that a Core Data object can be compared against. For example

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]; 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"count = %@", myNumber];
```

is perfectly valid if "count" is a Number attribute of the entity. It is similar to binding values to SQLite prepared statements.

If `%@` could be used for general string formatting in predicates, then there would be no need to have two different format specifiers `%K`  and `%@` for key paths and values.

Comment: Your interpretation is incorrect. %@ can be used to substitute in any object. Core Data has nothing to do with the validity of an arbitrary predicate.